# Build and run maven module before compiling phase

Tags: java, maven-2, preprocessor, maven-3

Is it possible to build one module and run it, before compile phase? Here are the details.

I have a project with this setup:

```
<modules>
  <module>preprocessor</module>
  <module>module1</module>
  <module>module2</module>
  ... more ...
</module>
```

*preprocessor* module contains some code that will process other code: generate some code and data inside other modules. I'm running it from terminal with 'mvn exec:java' and works fine.

However, I would like to automate this thing, so when other developers wants to compile/install the whole tree, maven first compile *preprocessor*, execute it with some parameters and continue with compile phase.

Also, can maven be instructed to not install this preprocessor module when 'mvn install' is run?

Thanks.

Comment: You can comment the modules in pom file that you don't want as a temporary work around.

Comment: True, but those modules will not be compiled in compilation phase. I assume you targeting that 'preprocess' module, but he must be compiled so preprocessing could be done.

Comment: May be you can give more details about the preprocessor module which will make it possible to give better hints.

Comment: Sure! Preprocessing module was done in clojure (actually it is java code that embeds clojure) and should read a file (which is clojure DSL) where is described which files to read and what tokens to replace in them, based on custom logic. Target files that will be replaced are couple of property files, a few xml files and (probably in future) some java code. Other modules depends on these property/xml files and would be nice if they could be generated before packaging/testing phase automatically, but with standard 'install/deploy', so migration to the new process could be painless as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First if you have a kind of a generator which sounds like so..you need to run it during the generate-resources life-cycle phase or if it's realy code which needs to be compiled in the generate-sources life-cylce. 
One very important thing is to do the generation localally in the preprocessor module and don't put results into other modules.
If you have the requirement to use the generated information in other modules you should put that into the resources folder which will be automatically be available as part of a jar which can be generated during the build process.
The generated jar can be used by other modules simply as a dependency.

Comment: Thanks! This sounds reasonable... but how to tell maven that during generate-resources phase go into preprocessor folder, compile java code and continue with the phase? Isn't generate-resources run before compile phase?

Comment: The compiling of Java code should be done by the maven-compiler-plugin and not by your plugin. Your Plugin/Task etc. should simply create the code into target/generated-code ? I'm not 100%sure about that. May be you can take a look at antlr3 plugin ?

Comment: Aaaa maybe I sound confusing...ultimate goal would be that maven during global generate-resource phase (invoked in project root) descend into preprocessor folder and invoke compile phase so it can compile preprocessor code; after this, let maven invoke preprocessor, generate resources and continue with compiling rest of the code.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the maven plugin http://code.google.com/p/java-comment-preprocessor/ which allows to make preprocessing of Java code

Comment: Thank you. It is very neat project and I was aware of it (I'm assuming you are the author), but didn't take it because I needed ability to interact with Java code. But I'll surely keep it in my toolbox since it solve the main thing I hate in Java: missing preprocessor :)